# error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Using Unity, I'm trying to add GameObjects with a particular script to an array. I've tried a bunch of different methods and ultimately I've ended up with this, and for the life of me I can't find why it's giving me the error, because everything I've googled for the last hour has said it's mostly from syntax and I cannot find the syntax error. I wonder if it wouldn't just make sense to use a get/set but I really don't understand how those are different from for loops. Thank you!

```
public class QuestFinderScript : MonoBehaviour {
GameObject[] objects;
public List<GameObject> interactables = new List<GameObject> ();
int interactablesSize;

void Start(){

    interactables = new List<GameObject> ();
    objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Untagged");
    interactablesSize = objects.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < interactablesSize; i++) {

        InteractionSettings iset = objects [i].GetComponent<InteractionSettings> ();
        if (iset != null) {
            interactables.Add [i];

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you uh...reviewed the syntax of [how you actually use `.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Um, yes? And this has worked for me before in other code, so I'm not sure what the problem is. When I do it with parens, it gives me the same error.

Comment: Add is a function and therefore you need a (). Something like this: `interactables.Add( iset.gameObject);`

Comment: Perfect, that solved my problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st problem: As Pogrammer says, Add is a function for list, not an indexer.

Add(i) is correct

Of course, the error is due to your 1st problem.

2nd problem: Interactables os list of GameObject, you try to add integer(i is integer) to list of GameObjects.

Review your code and understand what you are going to add to Interactables.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to your input, I've fixed it -- part of the problem was that I didn't realize the script I was referencing was a child, not a component of the gameobject itself. But if anyone's curious:

```
    interactables = new List<GameObject> ();
    objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("questable");
    interactablesSize = objects.Length;

    Debug.Log (interactablesSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < interactablesSize; i++) {

        InteractionSettings iset = objects [i].GetComponentInChildren<InteractionSettings> ();
        if (iset != null) {
            interactables.Add(iset.gameObject);
        }
    }
```